# use textField and listview.builder in bottom sheet

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hey everyone I'm new to flutter and I have a problem.
I want to create an application that users after tapping on the Btn the bottom sheet will be open and after that ( here problem ) show the text field(for search) and the listView.

problem: when I do this nothing show me( even the bottom sheet don't appear)

this is my code :

```
enter code here

                   GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            showModalBottomSheet(
                                // ---------------------//
                                context: context,

                                builder: (context) {
                                  return Container(
                                    color: Color(0xff737373),
                                    // to make the radius visible
                                    child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
                                        child: countriesInfo == null
                                            ? Center(
                                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                              )
                                            : Column(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Container(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                    child: TextField(
                                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                        labelText: 'country',
                                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  ListView.builder(
                                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                      return GestureDetector(
                                                        onTap: () {
                                                          _selectItem(countriesInfo[index]);
                                                        },
                                                        child: Container(
                                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                                                          height: 50,
                                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 10, offset: Offset(0, 10))],
                                                          ),
                                                          child: Row(
                                                            children: [
                                                              Image.network(
                                                                countriesInfo[index]._flag,
                                                                width: 50,
                                                                height: 50,
                                                              ),
                                                              Text(
                                                                countriesInfo[index]._name,
                                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                              ),
                                                            ],
                                                          ), // name of the country
                                                        ),
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                    itemCount: countriesInfo == null ? 0 : countriesInfo.length,
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              )),
                                  );
                                }); //  end bottom nav
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(35),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFFA3A3A3), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "${selectedCountry == null ? countriesInfo[0].name : selectedCountry!.name.toString()}",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

if know any documentation or idea tell me please thank you.

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: You didn't state the problem? But why aren't you using a button and you using a gesture detector over a container showing text & I'm sure its not rendering and showing a transparent darkened background. You can put the ListBuilder in an expanded thats should solve that if thats the issues you  facing.